# Authenticate user using Google auth API and calling SignInAsync not working as expected

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I'm trying to use Google to authenticate a user against my Asp.Net MVC application. The following is the code in the _LoginPartial that seems to be surfacing the problem:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
  @if (User?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated ?? false)
  {
    <li class="nav-item">
        <span class="navbar-text text-dark">Signed in as @User.Identity.Name!</span>
    </li>
  }
  else
    {
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignInWithGoogle">SignInWithGoogle</a>
    </li>
    }
</ul>
```

In fact, when I call the controller method, it does launch the Google log-in page, and appear to successfully log me in. I suspect the issue is with the callback method:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GoogleCallback()
    {
        var result = await _httpContextAccessor!.HttpContext!.AuthenticateAsync("Google");
        if (result.Succeeded && result.Principal != null)
        {
            var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(result.Principal);

            await _httpContextAccessor!.HttpContext!.SignInAsync(
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                claimsPrincipal,
                new AuthenticationProperties { 
                    IsPersistent = true,
                    AllowRefresh = true,
                    ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10),
                });

            HttpContext.User = claimsPrincipal;

            Console.WriteLine(User?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated); // Identity set here
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

The `Console.WriteLine` shows that the `User.Identity` is set; however, when it redirects back and loads the `_LoginPartial` the `User.Identity` is null.

I set up authentication like this:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie("Identity.External", options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        options.Cookie.Name = "Identity.External";
        options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
    })    
    .AddGoogle(options =>
    {
        options.ClientId = id;
        options.ClientSecret = secret;
        options.SignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
    })
```

Have I called `SignInAsync` incorrectly, or is there some additional step that I'm missing?

Comment: you must @inject UserManager UserManager in your viewPage

Comment: I'm not using UserManager to manage the users in this application